# Why does my layout of application change when changing a single ID?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating a series of `editText` boxes on `relative layout`. When i want to change one of the edit text boxes it changes my whole layout and everything becomes on top of each other. I programmed in `visual studio` and there was exact x,y coordinates for each item in design view and seems like all eclipse has is padding. Shouldn't the layout should be indifferent of the ID name and be able to change it anytime?. I also want to use the same layout on a different activity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your layout code. No one will be able to answer otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use relative layout, components are arranged according to respective position of each other like toRighOf "someid" or leftOf "someid", when you change id of any component, their relative positions change and your layout gets disturbed, so if you change id of any component, you have to manually set the relative positions of each component.

Comment: Your right. I figured this out right after I asked the question. When I changed the ID name I had to go back in the .xml and find all of the old position references and change them to the new one.